# Поиск компонент связности С++ ?

Tags: графы, алгоритм, java, c++

Пример кода на с++/java? Имеется ввиду, поиск компонент связности с помощью обхода в глубину/ширину. Собираюсь искать по матрице смежности.

Comment: Вопрос уточните: где собираетесь искать и пример какого кода - кода поиска?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю автору вопрса нужен алгоритм поиска компонент сязности, а не компонент сильной связности, а это совсем не одно и тоже!

```
    int n, a[100][100], cur = 0;
    fin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            fin >> a[i][j];
    vector <int> was(n, -1);
    queue <int> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (was[i] != -1)
           continue;
        q.push(i);
        while (!q.empty())
        {
              int v = q.front();
              q.pop();
              if (was[v] != -1)
                 continue;
              was[v] = cur;
              for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                  if (a[i][j] != 0 && was[j] == -1)
                     q.push(j);
        }
        cur++;
    }
```

Этот код считывает граф заданный матрицей смежности(но советую ипользовть списки смежности).
В итоге в векторе was для каждой вершины будет лежать номер ее компоненты связности, а cur - количесвто компонент связности.

Comment: В первом варианте сообщения вопрошалось именно о компонентах сильной связности. Кто знает, возможно, скоро вопрос эволюционирует в проблему изоморфизма графов.

Comment: К тому же, если перейти на сайт библиотеки, то можно без труда найти и другие алгоритмы. Вот, например, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/connected_components.html

Answer (score 3):

В Boost есть [библиотека](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/index.html) для работы с графами, вот о компонентах связности: [strong_components](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/strong_components.html).

> The strong_components() functions compute the strongly connected components of a directed graph using Tarjan's algorithm based on DFS.

Answer (score 0):

код считывает граф через список смежности. Заполнение идет путем считывания вершин одного ребра. Код для неориентированного графа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

/// <summary>
/// Обход графа в глубину
/// </summary>
/// <param name="graph"> граф представленный списком смежности </param>
/// <param name="v"> текущая вершина </param>
/// <param name="visited"> список помеченных вершин, в которых побывали </param>
void dfs(vector<vector<int>> &graph, int v, vector <int> &visited, vector<int> &component)
{
    visited[v] = 1; //отмечаем что были в вершине
    component.push_back(v); //добавляем вершину в компоненту

    for (int to : graph[v]) // перемешаемся по списку вершины
        if (!visited[to]) // если в вершине не были
            dfs(graph, to, visited, component); // двигаемся дальше
}

void findComps(vector<vector<int>> &graph, int v, vector<int> &visited, vector<int> &component)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i) // обнуляем все отметки
        visited[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v; ++i) //двигаемся по вершинам от 0
        if (!visited[i]) // если не были в вершине
        {
            component.clear(); // очищаем вектор компоненты
            dfs(graph, i, visited, component); // обход графа, начиня с первой вершины

            sort(component.begin(), component.end()); // сортируем вершины компоненты
            cout << "Component:" << endl; //вывод компонента
            for (int i = 0; i < component.size(); i++) //выводим все вершины компоненты
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < graph[component[i]].size(); j++) //выводим все смежные вершины и у текущей
                    cout << graph[component[i]][j] << " ";
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
}

int main()
{
    int vertexCount, edgeCount; //количество вершин и количество ребер
    vector<vector<int>> graph(vertexCount); //граф в списке смежности размером количество вершин
    vector<int> visited(vertexCount); //массив посещений размером количество вершин
    vector<int> component; //компонента, хранит вершины входящие в компоненту

    cout << "Enter count vertex and edge:\n";
    cin >> vertexCount >> edgeCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < edgeCount; i++) // считывание графа список смежности
    {
        int a, b;
        cout << "Enter vertex of edge:\n";
        cin >> a >> b;

        graph[a].push_back(b);
        graph[b].push_back(a);
    }

    findComps(graph, vertexCount, visited, component);
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста не копипастите код по нескольким ответам. Лучше в комментариях кидать ссылку на ваш первый ответ.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Просто недавно зарегистрировался на форуме. И сам толком не смог найти связного ответа и кода на эту задачу, поэтому был полон желания поделиться своим ответом :)